# How do I make a gradient opacity in an image?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, gradient, opacity

How do I make an image fade in qml? How do I achieve this effect? here I attach the image of how I want it to look

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A possible solution is to use [`OpacityMask`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-opacitymask.html) with a [`LinearGradient`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-lineargradient.html) as source

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 600
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Image {
        id: input
        source: "input.jpg"
        anchors.fill: parent

        OpacityMask {
            source: mask
            maskSource: input
        }

        LinearGradient {
            id: mask
            anchors.fill: parent
            gradient: Gradient {
                GradientStop { position: 0.2; color: "transparent"}
                GradientStop { position: 0.5; color: "white" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

While the accepted solution achieves the desired effect, it's not actually creating an opacity gradient in the original image (which is what I needed). It's just overlaying the `LinearGradient` on top of the image; the `OpacityMask` isn't doing anything and can be removed from that example. The white color at the bottom of the image is from the `LinearGradient`, not from the background.

Here's an example of how to create an opacity gradient in the original image. Note that the visibility of the "source image" (a `Rectangle`, in this case) and the `LinearGradient` are both `false`.

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 400
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    
    // The background, to ensure it's working
    Rectangle {
        color: "red"
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    // The "source image"
    Rectangle {
        id: blueBox
        color: "blue"
        anchors.fill: parent
        opacity: 0.5
        visible: false
    }
    
    LinearGradient {
        id: mask
        anchors.fill: blueBox
        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop {
                position: 0.2
                color: "transparent"
            }
            GradientStop {
                position: 0.5
                color: "white"
            }
        }
        visible: false
    }
    
    OpacityMask {
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: blueBox
        maskSource: mask
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With few lines code:

```
LinearGradient {
    source: Image { source: 'qrc:/Login Images/ir.svg' }
        anchors.fill: parent
        start: Qt.point(0, 0)
        end: Qt.point(0, 300)
        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "white" }
            GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "teal" }
        }
    }
```