# QML PieSlice Gradient colour

Tags: qt, qml, qtcharts

I'm using a PieSeries in QML as a way to create a makeshift mask.
I have a circular animated gif and on top of it, I've added a PieSeries.
The PieSeries has 3 PieSlices. 2 of them are "black" essentially blocking out there corresponding portions of the gif. The remaining PieSlice is transparent.
This works fine, but I would like the 2 black PieSlices to have a gradient to them so that their edge is not so obvious (gradient transparency).

I've tried using a LinearGradient with an OpacityMask as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48472703/how-do-i-make-a-gradient-opacity-in-an-image-qml), but this did not have any effect when used on a PieSlice.

Any suggestions would be appreciated :)

Here's my code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtCharts 2.2
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Item {
    anchors.fill: parent //Fill the gif area

    ChartView {
        id: chart
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        height: parent.height+200
        width: parent.width
        legend.visible: false
        antialiasing: false
        backgroundColor: "transparent"

        PieSeries {
            id: pieOuter
            size: 1.5
            holeSize: 0.2
            PieSlice { id: black1; value: 1; color: "black"; borderColor: "transparent" }
            PieSlice { id: valSlice; value: d.val; color: "transparent"; borderColor: "transparent" }
            PieSlice { id: black2; value: 1 - d.val; color: "black"; borderColor: "transparent" }
        }

    }
    OpacityMask{
        source: mask
        maskSource: black1
    }
    LinearGradient {
        id: mask
        anchors.fill: black1
        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop { position: 0.2; color: "transparent"}
            GradientStop { position: 0.5; color: "white" }
        }
    }

}
```

Note: d.val here holds a value between 0 and 1

**Edit**
Some images to help visualise what I'm trying to achieve:
The GIF that I'm starting off with ([source](https://dribbble.com/shots/3751780-Formwave) - original file was too large to attach):

[Snapshot of original Gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeUPV.gif)

This is how it is currently animated to look:

[Low d.val](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgV4n.gif)

[Higher d.val](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHeX5.gif)

[Max d.val](https://i.stack.imgur.com/en3yH.gif)

This is what I want it to actually look like (depicted here for d.val):

[Higher d.val with gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MU6Xz.gif)

Comment: Are you only using PieSeries to create the mask effect?

Comment: Yes, it is just to block out certain parts of the underlying gif depending on what the value of d.val is

Comment: you are using incorrect elements, you could place an image of what you want next to the gif to understand you better.

Comment: I've attached a few images to show what I have at the moment and also what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Could you tell me what the correct elements are that I should use to achieve this effect?