# Edit properties of part of an image in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I need to edit opacity (or any property) of specific part of an image in QML. My purpose is to make an animation that goes through the image from left to right, but I wonder how to access a part of the image and what to use.

Comment: I think your best bet is to actually work in layers (like old-school sprite-games). The part that should be behind the moving subject is declared first in qml, then the moving part, then the part that should be in front

Comment: Check out [opacitymask](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-opacitymask.html), it might help you.

Comment: see this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48472703/how-do-i-make-a-gradient-opacity-in-an-image/48472948#48472948